# Учебник Lua

Tags: книги, lua

Здравствуйте, уже 2-ой день ищу в гугле, на форумах учебник по Lua. 
Я нашёл только документацию, но к сожалению, она очень мелкая.
**Имеете ли вы нормальное** (*то значит полное*) **пособие по этому языку?**
P.S. Английский переношу плохо, буду читать только если выхода больше не будет.

Comment: Самый лучший учебник по Lua - это книга "Programming in Lua" (издание 1 описывает Lua 5.0, издание 2 - Lua 5.1, издание 3 - Lua 5.2).  Книжка написана автором языка Lua, очень легко и занимательно читается.  Говорят, третье издание переведено на русский.

Comment: Этот вопрос уже задавался и имеет решение: [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235171/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-lua/235172#235172)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть хорошая книга по данной теме Lua (programming language) от авторов Jesse Russell и Ronald Cohn. Единственный минус, ну может для некоторых и плюс, что она не переведена. Но книга очень хорошая. Нужны только определенные навыки английского.

- [Lua (programming language)](http://www.books.ru/books/lua-programming-language-3468468/?show=1)

Русская документация точно не подходит?

- [Справочное руководство по языку Lua 5.1](http://www.lua.ru/doc/)

Но если и это не понравилось, то держи неплохой электронный учебничек

- [Руководство по языку программирования Lua](http://luagml.ucoz.ru/doc/lua/content.html)

Comment: Попробовал читать на англ., понравилось, оказывается, я хорошо его знаю ! :) Спасибо.

Comment: Знаю, всмысле, английский :)